# Auto Login with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends! Every morning when I start my internet, I have to open a page, which redirects me to a login screen and I login from there. Since the username/password values are prepopulated, I have to just hit the Login button.

Now once in a day is ok but sometimes during the day, the connection just goes off and I am redirected to the Login page again.

Can I automate this. THe Login button on the redirected page looks like this

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Login" onclick="return checking();" />
```

What I am looking for is the following

- A Page that will refresh itself every 5 minutes. If the url of the page starts with https://login.broadband.in (that means the connection is off and redirection tool place), then call the javascript function  checking() so that it auto logs in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

[Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) is what you want.

Comment: I installed Greasemonkey but not sure what do I do now. This is a little new to me and some extra help is appreciated